# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple @Body method annotations found. (parameter #2) for method APIServiceDafater.sendFood

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, frombodyattribute

I send the following 3 parameters, but it is not sent

@POST("dafater/insertNewFoodsController")
Single sendFood(@Body List Foods,@Body Printer printer,@Query("warning") String warning);

server is asp.net

:( :( :(

Comment: It is not allowed to pass multiple `@Body` parameters to a controller method

Comment: You should give more details about your question.